# ReactNative TextInput GIF Keyboard Insert

Tags: react-native

I want to utilize the GIF insertion features of Android and iOS keyboards, but when I try, I get a notify that, "____ doesn't support image insertion here". How can I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I installed this package and it worked

https://github.com/Gustash/react-native-image-keyboard

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your Answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be preferable if you could answer the Question in your own words here and link only as a reference. How does it work? How is it used? Please show how it solves the issue.